# DNN 7 General Exception

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am creating Costume DNN Module but I have "General Exception" happening recently. just want to ask if anyone get this error " General Exception" and how to fix it

```
AssemblyVersion: 7.0.5

PortalID: -1

PortalName: 

UserID: -1

UserName: 

ActiveTabID: -1

ActiveTabName: 

RawURL: 

AbsoluteURL: 

AbsoluteURLReferrer: 

UserAgent: 

DefaultDataProvider: DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID: 19286ea9-9154-4453-93d3-f58e3e143f64

InnerException: Error Creating BusinessControllerClass 'DotNetNuke.Modules.ResourceModule.Components.FeatureController' of module(ResourceModule) id=(637) in tab(144) and portal(0) 

FileName: 

FileLineNumber: 0

FileColumnNumber: 0

Method: System.Activator.CreateInstance

StackTrace: 

Message: System.Exception: Error Creating BusinessControllerClass 'DotNetNuke.Modules.ResourceModule.Components.FeatureController' of module(ResourceModule) id=(637) in tab(144) and portal(0) ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModuleList(Int32 PortalID) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModuleList(Int32 PortalID)

Source: 

Server Name:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an easy one, fixed in the next Template release. https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/discussions/440995

Basically, update your .DNN file to include the proper namespace for your BusinessController class, I left a hardcoded one in there by mistake in one of the templates.

Comment: FYI, I hope to do another template release in the next few days

Comment: Discussion link is not found any more.

Comment: Discussion for my templates can be found on my DNNCHAT site